# Where does my browser save youtube videos?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-cache

If I suddenly lose my Internet connection, all of the Youtube videos that were pre-loaded by my browser (Chrome or Firefox) can still be watched and watched again, since they are saved somewhere in the memory of my PC.

Where does my browser save such videos? In what format?

I am interested in both Windows and Ubuntu-similar operative systems.

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/399983/in-which-temporary-folder-on-my-windows-7-computer-can-i-find-copies-of-recently) that already explains some questions you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

its in your cache folder

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
```

(but its all in chunks, so to see whats what you can use portable tool like [chromecacheview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html))